# Spring unit tests [webflux, cloud]

Tags: spring, mockito, spring-webflux, junit5

I am new to the topic of unit testing and my question is whether I should perform the test as such of each line of code of a method or in what ways I can perform these tests to have a good coverage, if also, should exceptions be evaluated or not?

If for example I have this service method that also uses some helpers that communicate with other microservices, someone could give me examples of how to perform, thank you very much.

```
public Mono<BankAccountDto> save(BankAccountDto bankAccount) {
  var count = findAccountsByCustomerId(bankAccount.getCustomerId()).count();

  var customerDto = webClientCustomer
        .findCustomerById(bankAccount.getCustomerId());
  var accountType = bankAccount.getAccountType();

  return customerDto
      .zipWith(count)
      .flatMap(tuple -> {
        final CustomerDto custDto = tuple.getT1();
        final long sizeAccounts = tuple.getT2();
        final var customerType = custDto.getCustomerType();
        
        if (webClientCustomer.isCustomerAuthorized(customerType, accountType, sizeAccounts)) {
          return saveBankAccountAndRole(bankAccount);
        }
        return Mono.error(new Exception("....."));
      });

}
```

---

### EDIT

```
public Mono<BankAccountDto> save(BankAccountDto bankAccount) {
    var count = findAccountsByCustomerId(bankAccount.getCustomerId()).count();

    var customerDto = webClientCustomer
            .findCustomerById(bankAccount.getCustomerId());

    return customerDto
            .zipWith(count)
            .flatMap(tuple -> {
              final var customDto = tuple.getT1();
              final var sizeAccounts = tuple.getT2();
              final var accountType = bankAccount.getAccountType();

             // EDITED
              return webClientCustomer.isCustomerAuthorized(customDto, accountType, sizeAccounts)
                      .flatMap(isAuthorized -> {
                        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isAuthorized)) {
                          return saveBankAccountAndRole(bankAccount);
                        }
                        return Mono.error(new Exception("No tiene permisos para registrar una cuenta bancaria"));
                      });
            });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want to unit test this code, you would need to mock dependencies such as `webClientCustomer`.

Then you should always test whatever are the relevant paths within the code. Looking at your code I only see three relevant ones to be tested:

- the method returns an empty `Mono` if `webClientCustomer.findCustomerById(bankAccount.getCustomerId());` returns an empty `Mono`;
- `saveBankAccountAndRole(bankAccount)` is called and your `save()` method actually returns whatever `saveBankAccountAndRole(bankAccount)` returns. This would should happen if `webClientCustomer.isCustomerAuthorized(customerType, accountType, sizeAccounts)` is `true`;
- the method returns an exception if `webClientCustomer.isCustomerAuthorized(customerType, accountType, sizeAccounts)` is `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made a small modification to my code and well, debugging I ran into a problem. To the method **isCustomerAuthorized** I send a **customDto** but inside that method the property **customerId** is null while the other properties have data. I know it because I have debugged, what is the reason?

Comment: I don't even know that `customerId` is in your code, so I can't answer your question. Nevertheless, that has nothing to do with your original answer, which I have answered.